# What is the correct way to broadcast weights in PyTorch for distributed training on multiple GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed-computing

Suppose I have updated the neural network weights via some operation on the **master** node (`rank = 0`), and I would like to broadcast updated weights to all other workers in the group.

In the [torch.distributed API](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#synchronous-and-asynchronous-collective-operations) I see several functions:

- torch.distributed.broadcast
- torch.distributed.broadcast_object_list
- torch.distributed.broadcast_multigpu

Seems, like a simple option:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    dist.broadcast(param, src=0)
```

Would work. The third option seems to be more specific for training on single node Multi GPU but it is not clear how?

What is the recommended way to broadcast parameters for NN?

If it is done prior to the training loop, does the default option `async_op=False` mean, that other processes would not start execution their part of the loop until the main process broadcasts the weights?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code to update weight for all ranks from rank 0 to another rank

```
def sync_initial_weights(model, rank, world_size):
    for param in model.parameters():
        if rank == 0:
            # Rank 0 is sending it's own weight
            # to all it's siblings (1 to world_size)
            for sibling in range(1, world_size):
                dist.send(param.data, dst=sibling)
        else:
            # Siblings must recieve the parameters
            dist.recv(param.data, src=0)
```